# Soap Server Images

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

What the best way of passing images over a soap server?

I'm using WCF 4.0 and flex for my front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say if this is the best, but I have used Base64 encoding to send binary data as XML within SOAP as well as AMQP.  Worked well for what I needed, but YMMV.

Comment: Base64 is the ONLY way to encode binary data through a text format.